# django email validation issue

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm trying to create a custom column type using `django_tables2` so that I can render contact details as a `mailto:` link when the result is a valid email address, and just standard text otherwise.

The issue that I'm having is that my value seems to be returned as iterated characters, and as per the code below, the first character of the email address is render as part of `mailto:` whilst the second character of the email address is rendered in the column. Aside from `validate_email` I have tried `if "@" in` and `regex`, all returning the same iterated character results.

```
class ContactColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self,value):
        try:
            validate_email(value)
            return format_html('''<a href="mailto:{}">{}</a>''',*value)
        except ValidationError:
            return value
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to successfully render either a `mailto:` link or just standard text based on valid email address? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is your `*value` argument.

The asterisk means to unpack a sequence (here, a string) into its parts (characters) and use those for the arguments. (Search for "Python argument unpacking" to learn more.)

Instead, just do:

```
format_html('''<a href="mailto:{}">{}</a>''', value, value)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. Really appreciate the explanation.